MacOS Swift (UI): Prevent App Window Opening
Context
I have a MacOS application built in Swift (UI), which I'd like to only open from the menu bar, and not from its own main (empty) app window. It also has notifications; I've put the launch code for these 3 parts below, but please feel free to ask for further context/code snippets.
Issue
Currently, every time it launches, the main (empty) app window opens--which is unintended--and the icon pops up in the menu bar--intended.
What I've Tried
Removing the whole var body part or just the Settings{} block, but found out that both are necessary when implementing/comforming to the App protocol:


Additional context from Quote_DropletApp.swift:
This is where the code block above is as well, which is the only file in my codebase having launch control over these windows:
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    static private(set) var instance: AppDelegate!
    lazy var statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    let menu = ApplicationMenu()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        AppDelegate.instance = self
        statusBarItem.button?.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("QuoteDropletSmall"))
        statusBarItem.button?.imagePosition = .imageLeading
        statusBarItem.menu = menu.createMenu()
        
        // auto-start:
        
        let mainAppIdentifier = "com.Daggerpov.Quote-Droplet"
        let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
        let isRunning = !runningApps.filter { $0.bundleIdentifier == mainAppIdentifier }.isEmpty
        
        
        if !isRunning {
            var pathComponents = (Bundle.main.bundlePath as NSString).pathComponents
            pathComponents.removeLast()
            pathComponents.removeLast()
            pathComponents.removeLast()
            pathComponents.removeLast()
            let newPath = NSString.path(withComponents: pathComponents)
            
            NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(newPath)
        }
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
            if success {
                NotificationScheduler.shared.scheduleNotifications()
            } else if let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}


In SwiftUI you can use MenuBarExtra in your scene to add an icon to the menu bar.
The contents of MenuBarExtra is a SwiftUI view that is rendered when the user clicks on the menu bar icon, while the label is the view that is rendered in the menu bar.
You could use something like
struct Quote_DropletApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra {
            SettingsView()
        } label: {
          HStack {
           Image("QuoteDropletSmall").aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).scaledToFit().frame(width:16,height:16,alignment: .center)
          }
    }
}

And remove what you have in the AppDelegate

My first attempted solution was close, but I needed to keep the Settings{} block, and simply remove the inner EmptyView():
@main
struct Quote_DropletApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        Settings {
//            EmptyView() I just needed to remove this one line, keeping `Settings{}`
        }
    }
}

Now, my desired behavior of my menu bar showing up without the extraneous window is achieved 
