Issue with Empty Window Appearing on App Launch for macOS App - Help Needed

I've been struggling with a problem for the past couple of weeks, and I can't seem to figure out the cause. I'm developing an app that allows users to easily switch languages on macOS. The app is ready, and I submitted it for review, but the problem is that Apple has been unable to approve it for the past two weeks due to an issue.
Upon launching the app, an empty window/container appears, but I cannot reproduce this issue on my own Macs (M1, M2, M3). On my machines, the app works perfectly and launches without the empty window appearing.
Does anyone know how I can identify and resolve this issue? I’ve attached a screenshot of the empty window that needs to be removed from the code, as well as a snippet of the code that might be responsible for it.
I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to fix this, as I’m unable to reproduce the error on my end.
Thanks in advance for your help!
@main
struct LanguageSwitcherApp: App {

    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        Settings {
            EmptyView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(after: .appInfo) {
                Button("Show Language Switcher") {
                    appDelegate.showLanguageSwitcher()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem?
    private var languageSwitcherPanel: LanguageSwitchPanel?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        if let button = statusItem?.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: "icon_top")
            button.action = #selector(showMenu)
            button.target = self
        }

        showLanguageSwitcher()
    }

    @objc private func showMenu() {

        let menu = NSMenu()

        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Close Type Switch", action: #selector(closeApp), keyEquivalent: "q"))

        statusItem?.menu = menu
        statusItem?.button?.performClick(nil)
        statusItem?.menu = nil
    }

    func showLanguageSwitcher() {
        guard languageSwitcherPanel == nil else { return }

        let panel = LanguageSwitchPanel()
        let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: LanguageSwitchView())
        panel.contentView = hostingController.view
        panel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

        languageSwitcherPanel = panel
    }

    @objc private func closeApp() {
        NSApp.terminate(nil)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LanguageSwitchPanelRepresentable()
            .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
}

struct LanguageSwitchPanelRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let panel = LanguageSwitchPanel()
        let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: LanguageSwitchView())
        panel.contentView = hostingController.view
        panel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        return NSView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}

I tried testing the app on my MacBook models (M1, M2, M3) and all of them functioned as expected, launching the app without any additional windows appearing. I also checked the code for any unintended window launches or containers and could not find any issues.
I expected the app to launch without any extra empty windows or containers, but when Apple tested it, they encountered an issue with an empty window appearing upon launch.

Your Settings presents an EmptyView() this will cause a blank window to appear.

Do a search for "Type Switch Settings" and see where you are setting the Window Title and then look what you're calling from that code. I'm guessing you are calling the Settings view which in turn calls an EmptyView()

I initially tried that as well. But the most surprising part is that I couldn’t find the  "Type Switch Settings" as a title written single line.

Should the window not appear or should the window not be empty? Have you deleted the container folder?

No, the window should not appear at all, it appears together with the main application during startup, in the screenshot there is a blue icon with a tongue.
This is the application, and the empty window next to it is what should not appear during startup

What happens when you open settings? Does it show the same window title? Try changing the settings view to something else a blue view or something. You should replace the settings command with nothing and not allow settings to be opened as well. I believe it’s the appSettings command placement

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79068815/macos-swift-ui-prevent-app-window-opening?rq=2   Check this answer also might work better for you than Settings link

Thank you all for your participation, I solved the problem as follows:
if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
window.close()
